# Display textView in listView

Tags: android, android-listview, textview

How to display the `total amount` beside `Total` ?

[image]

**Code Snippet**

```
        View claims = inflater.inflate(R.layout.receipt_text, container, false);
        v=(ImageView)claims.findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
        listV = (ListView) claims.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        UnderListViewButton=(Button)claims.findViewById(R.id.btnSave); // save button below listView
        FrameLayout footerLayout = (FrameLayout)getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.under_listview_button,null);
        UnderListViewButton = (Button) footerLayout.findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
        ViewGroup footer = (ViewGroup) getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.total,null);
        listV.addFooterView(footer);
        listV.addFooterView(footerLayout);


   @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 0:
                result = data.getStringExtra("text"); //67
                name = data.getStringExtra("a"); //Project
                description = data.getStringExtra("c");
                as = as + Long.parseLong(result);
                Log.d("FIRST", "result:" + result);
                Text = "  " + name + " " + "RM" + result + "";
                if (mClickedPosition == -1) {
                    m_listItems.add(Text);
                    m_listBitmapItems.add(Global.img);

                } else {
                    m_listItems.set(mClickedPosition, Text);
                    m_listBitmapItems.set(mClickedPosition, Global.img);

                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                listV.setAdapter(adapter);
                break;

                case 2: .......
                .......
           }
               long samount=as+bs+cs+ds+es; // total get correctly
               Toast.makeText(getActivity(),samount+"", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
         }
```

**receipt_text_xml** // for the main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="@string/text" android:textSize="20sp" />

<ListView android:id="@+id/listView1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />


</LinearLayout>
```

**total.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="51dp"
    android:text="Total"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:background="@drawable/border_text"
    android:layout_x="10dp"
    android:layout_y="-5dp">

</TextView>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Comment: Why wanted to close my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to display the total amount beside Total ?

Because `total` `TextView` is inside `footer` so, do it as:

**1.** Declare `footer` at class level instead of inside any method and initialize it before adding to ListView footer :

```
...
footer = (AbsoluteLayout) getActivity().
      getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.total,null);
listV.addFooterView(footer);
...
```

**2.** In `onActivityResult` use  `findViewById` using `footer` to access `total` `TextView`:

```
TextView totalTextView = (TextView)footer.findViewById(R.id.tv);
totalTextView.setText("Total :"+ samount);
```

Comment: Do I need to add one more `TextView` in `total.xml` ?

Comment: @Tony: Yes add it if want to show total amount at right align and `Total` text in left side align

Comment: If I use your code no need right? since you have used `totalTextView.setText("Total :"+ samount);`

Comment: Do I need to put `totalTextView` as global and move  `totalTextView = (TextView)footer.findViewById(R.id.tv);` to `onCreateView` ?

Comment: @Tony: put it inside `onActivityResult `

Comment: It works after I put `totalTextView` as global and move `totalTextView = (TextView)footer.findViewById(R.id.tv);` to `onCreateView`. `footer` cannot be resolved if I put it inside `onActivityResult`

Comment: @Tony: Good if working both is same either make `footer` global as i told you in point 1 in my answer or  make totalTextView as global

Comment: Thanks. Highly Appreciated :)

Comment: Do you know how to add listView with image dynamically ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34184455/how-do-i-add-a-listview-with-image-and-text-dynamically/34184691#34184691